# Set theory possible values

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

I'm studying for an upcoming exam and a practice question stumped me. It is asking for possible values A), B), and C) could have. $C^c$ means the complement of $C$. Am I right when I reason that A) would just be any number smaller than 0.7, or is it warranted to be more precise?

Family of events → [0, 1]

$P(A \cup B \cup C) = 0.7$

A)  $P(A \cup B)$

B)  $P((A \cup B) \cap C^c)$

C)  $P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)$

Comment: "Any number smaller than $0.7$" would also include values like $-1$. On the other hand, it would exclude $0.7$ itself, which is possible if $C\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: You have a point, so a good answer would be any number between 0 up to but not including 0.7. There is no way to interpret a precise value when asking for possible values?

Comment: With the given information, you won't be able to give a precise value. Just like you cannot give a precise value for my height if I tell you I'm less tall than Abraham Lincoln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Look at the extreme cases for (A) and (B).

(A) If $C=\varnothing$, then $P(A\cup B)=0.7$. If $A=B=\varnothing,P(C)=0.7$, then $P(A\cup B)=0$. So

$$0\le P(A\cup B)\le0.7$$

(B) If $C=A\cup B$, then $(A \cup B) \cap C^c=\varnothing$ so $P((A \cup B) \cap C^c)=0$. If $C=\varnothing$ , then $P(A\cup B)=0.7$ and $(A \cup B) \cap C^c=A \cup B$ so $P((A \cup B) \cap C^c)=0.7$. So again

$$0\le P((A \cup B) \cap C^c)\le0.7$$

(C) By repeated application of De Morgan's theorem, $A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c = (A \cup B \cup C)^c$, so

$$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)=1-P(A \cup B \cup C)=0.3$$

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the thorough explanation. I should have looked at the extreme cases just like you suggested.